# jQuery Accordion alternative (without jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have created  jQuery accordion in

"open accordion based on current URL" and "highlighted current  articles".

It was working.

But I have add two JS files.

For this JS File we are combined and file size will be 67KB.

It is very big size JS file.

what alternative do we have?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    header: '.menuitem'
     }); 
     $(".menuitem").click(function(event){
    window.location.hash=this.hash;
     });
     $(".closelink").click(function(event){
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
     });
   });
});  
$(function(){
    var current1 = window.location.href;
    $(".nav li a[href*='"+current1+"']").parents("li").addClass("current");
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="menuitem" href="#1">FIRST SECTION</h3>
    <!-- accordion panel -->
        <div class="panelBody">
            <ul class="nav menuside">
                <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/software-testing-introduction-importance.html">Introduction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/software-testing-seven-principles.html">Seven Principles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/software-testing-lifecycle.html">SDLC vs STLC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/software-testing-life-cycle.html">Testing Life Cycle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/manual-testing.html">Manual Testing</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end accordion panel -->
        </div>
    <h3 class="menuitem" href="#2">SECOND SECTION</h3> 
    <!-- accordion panel -->
        <div class="panelBody">
            <ul class="nav menuside">
                <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/software-testing-techniques-3.html">Use Case Testing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/testing-review.html">Static Testing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/testing-estimation.html">Estimation Techniques</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/test-plan.html">Test Plan Document</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.guru99.com/software-defect.html">What is Bug</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- end accordion panel -->
        </div>
    <!-- end accordion -->
</div>
```

Comment: how about this http://uniondesign.ca/simple-accordion-without-jquery-ui/ ?

Comment: I have try this http://uniondesign.ca/simple-accordion-without-jquery-ui/ but "open accordion based on current URL" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `$.slideToggle()` which is a native jQuery method. You can easily build an accordion using it: https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

This is just some hint on how to start:

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
```